# Virt-Manager-0.10.0 - GTK3

Tags: 13.04, gtk3, gtk-2, virt-manager

Every time when I try to start virt-manager-0.10.0 I get the following error:

```
Error starting virtual machine manager: Requiring namespace 'GTK' version '2.0', but '3.0' is already loaded
```

The exact issue you can find here (screenshots): 
imageshack.us/photo/my-images/30/e574.png 
imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/ekxi.png

I also tried to start the program with the shell command

```
sudo ./virt-manager
```

but I got the same error.

I installed it over this ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~jacob/+archive/virtualisation

I´m using Ubuntu 13.04, how can I fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo virt-manager`?

Comment: In the shell there is nothing, only the virt-manager error window opened, with the same error described in my question.

Comment: Virt-manager with Ubuntu 13.04 is [version 0.9.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/virt-manager), not 0.10. Please edit your question with all details: how you installed it, why you need a newer version, etc.

Comment: @NicolasNox Well, this is not helping really. Please include the details I asked for in my previous comment. And **edit** your question instead of posting comments to provide more details, that's how this site works. So please remove your comment and add the screenshots **in your question**.